# Can I trust LPS?

Tags: malware

[LPS](http://www.spi.dod.mil/lipose.htm) protects against spyware/malware by booting an OS from trusted media without reading from hard drives. However, not all components are open source. How do I know the US DoD didn't include malicious code itself?

Comment: Short answer: you don't? But it's the same for any closed source code.

Comment: And not only for closed source but even for open source because you usually don't verify that the software you run was build from the original sources. Thus if you don't trust the origin of the software don't use it.

Comment: Let's not forget the hardware either. Should you trust your processor?

Comment: And of course why should you trust any information you get here.